# Cassandra source -> sink replication

Tags: cassandra, replication, mdc

Is is possible to organize one way replication between data centers (DC).
Let's say we have two DCs: A and B.
I want all data written to nodes in DC A to be copied to DC B, but none of data written in DC B should go to A.
Is it possible with Cassandra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get close to that by using two keyspaces.  In Cassandra, keyspaces control how many replicas of each partition are kept in each data center.

So for data you write to A that you want replicated in B, you would create tables in a keyspace defined to replicate in both data centers like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE both WITH replication = {
    'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'A': '1', 'B': '1'};
```

But if you write to this keyspace in DC B, it will also replicate the write to A.

Then for data you want to write to DC B and not have it replicated to A, you would create tables in a keyspace that only keeps replicas in B, like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE bonly WITH replication = {
    'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'B': '1'};
```

With the second keyspace, you can actually issue the writes to nodes in DC A, and the data will be routed to B and only stored there.